# Simple CSV import function in Rails that takes the 'table' name as a variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I am creating an application that has many different types of objects and I want to enable the user to upload to any of them. There are lots of guides online to creating an import function within 1 specific model, but I do not want to duplicate the code within each model. Is there a neater way?

For example, Product.create! row.to_hash, how can I use a variable instead of hardcoding 'Product'?

Answer (score 1):

`constantize` will turn a class name into an actual class object.

```
# params = { table: 'products' }

klass = params[:table].classify.constantize # => Product
klass.create! row.to_hash # or whatever
```